# VBA CDO Runtime Error 429

Tags: vba, plc, scada

Having issue getting this vba remote email send script to work.

Run-time error 429 
ActiveX component can’t create object.

I've downloaded Microsoft CDO 1.21 Library, registered cdo.dll cmd prompt as Administrator, and referenced it.

.dll Location: C:\Program Files\ExchangeMapi\cdo.dll

OS: Windows 7 Professional, 32 bit, Service Pack 1.

Application with VBA: Iconics ScriptWorx32

Code:

```
Public Sub SendEmail(nFrom As String, nSubject As String, nOutGoingServer As String, _
                     nMessage As String, nPassword As String, nUserName As String, _
                     nServerPort As Long, nTo As String, Optional nIntProxyPort As Long)

  Dim Msg As Object
  Dim Confg As Object
  Dim Flds As Variant  

  Set Msg = CreateObject("CDO.Message")  
  Set Confg = CreateObject("CDO.Configuration")    

  Confg.Load -1
  Set Flds = Confg.Fields
  With Flds
      .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
      .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
      .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = nUserName 
      .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = nPassword 
      .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = nOutGoingServer
      .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = 2
      .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = nServerPort
      ' If using internet proxy
      .Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/urlproxyserver") = nIntProxyPort 
     .Update
  End With

  nMessage = nMessage & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
  "THIS IS AN AUTOMATED REPSONSE FROM ADMIN"

  With Msg
      Set .Configuration = Confg
          .To = nTo
          .From = nFrom 
          .Subject = nSubject
          .TextBody = nMessage
          .Send
  End With

End sub
```

I'm wondering if this software built in some sort of cdo.dll class instantiating block so you have buy their software GUI version. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Comment: @TimWilliams Sorry I forgot to add that: Set Msg = CreateObject

Comment: You have two of those lines - which one errors?

Comment: Can you run this from (eg) Excel ?

Comment: @TimWilliams This machine doesn't have MS Office, licensed that is. It has a trial version of office I believe. I may give that a try. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: @TimWilliams I may also try this in vbs outside of the platform I’m developing in to see if that's the constraint. If so, I may pipe from vba to vbs and then execute. Thanks for getting me thinking about this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using a different library: cdosys.dll instead of cdo.dll, reference: Microsoft CDO For Windows 2000 Library.